# Static logger class consideration

Tags: c#

I've found out some logger class and I am not so sure whether this class is really thread safe. True is that the `Log` method implements lock but access to class itself by multi threads will not raise problems? It consider me becase `TextWriter tw` is static so it means class has only one copy of `tw` and during each thread will access it can raise problems or not? BTW please take a look do you have any other objections here?:

```
public static class Logger
{
    static readonly TextWriter tw; 
    private static readonly object _syncObject = new object();

    static Logger(string SPath)
    {
        tw = TextWriter.Synchronized(File.AppendText(SPath + "\\Log.txt")); 
    }


    public static void Write(string logMessage)
    {
        try
        {
            Log(logMessage, tw);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            tw.Close();
        }
    }

    public static void Log(string logMessage, TextWriter w)    {
   // only one thread can own this lock, so other threads
   // entering this method will wait here until lock is
   // available.
   lock(_syncObject) {
      w.WriteLine("{0} {1}", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(),
          DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString());
      w.WriteLine("  :");
      w.WriteLine("  :{0}", logMessage);
      w.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
      // Update the underlying file.
      w.Flush();
   }
}
}
```

---

Second version for further dicsuss purposes:

```
 public static class Logger
    {
        static StreamWriter  sw; 
        private static readonly object _syncObject = new object();

        static Logger(string SPath)
        {
           lock(_syncObject)
           {
           StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(SPath));
           }    
    }
    ....
```

Comment: why not just use some ready [async logger](http://www.dotnetlogging.com/)?

Comment: what do you think either is better to use TextWriter.Synchronized in the constructor which will make lock on tw or to use this in constructor: lock(_syncObject) { using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path)) { ... } } and make a lock around it ?

Comment: if you're asking me, I'd say, don't use any locking, and don't write your own logger. The code doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is thread safe because every path uses the Log static method which uses a lock on the static _syncObject. This means that every thread that attempts to Log(..) will block if somebody else is logging.

However, if you call the Log method directly rather than the Write method, and you pass in a TextWriter that is being used by other threads, then that's not safe.

Comment: doeas it mean that TextWriter.Synchronized  is something like lock so every thread accessing clas is waiting as well on tw to be free such as lock in Log() function?

Comment: if i would have normal textwriter, streamwriter or wahtever in constructor then it would make me to make also lock() on that and because i am using TextWriter.Synchronized method i am not longer dont need to make lock right?

Comment: Erm, why isn't Write thread-safe exactly? It calls synchronized textwriter (which is thread-safe in my knowledge) + calls function Log to do the logging part (which is also thread-safe as you've said it yourself as well).

Comment: what do you think either is better to use TextWriter.Synchronized in the constructor which will make lock on tw or to use this in constructor: lock(_syncObject) { using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path)) { ... } } and make a lock around it ?

Comment: @walter Write is always thread safe, and multiple calls to Log with an external TextWriter is also thread safe unless you write to that external TW in some external threads directly without going through Logger.Log(..) makes sense?

Comment: As for the TextWriter.Synchronized, you're probably right that Logger.Write is using double thread safety. However, the Logger.Log can be used with an external non-Synchronized logger, which is why it needs the lock().

Comment: As for what is best, imo it's much better to use a proper logging framework/library than something like this. Try the .NET trace listeners etc. or NLog or something like that.

Comment: @Milthon: please explain because i dont get something at all. Does this Synchronized method of textWriter makes lock on it? Lets say i would not use that one but normall stream text writer or something without synchornized then inside constructor should i make manually the lock like this: lock(_syncObject) { using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path)) { ... } }

Comment: The main problem is that you have one concern in mind, namely logging to file, while the author of the code seems to have had two concerns: 1) logging to file, and 2) logging to a memory-stream or similar for testing purposes. So he has some scenario (2) where he needs to pass a non-thread safe TextWriter to his Logger and therefore he needs it to be able to make writing to that stream thread safe using the lock().

Comment: i want to understand one thing because i know Log method is thread save no concern on my mind. But when i am looking at whats inside constructor if i see some variable like tw which is not under lock() then its not thread safe because to be thread safe it should be between lock() to prevent other thread to wait when some thread is using it and if there is not lock() on tw i assume that Synchronized keyword of textwriter doing this lock other way textwriter should be under lock. Thats my thinking on it could you tell if i am correct or not?

Comment: The static tw is private (not specified => most restrictive = private) so any private static members will be thread safe as long as all access-paths to that member is locked, then that member will also be thread safe. Meaning that if you implement other public methods on the Logger which accesses 'tw', you should use a lock on those as well unless you want to rely on the Synchronized part.

Comment: ok two more questions. Still unanswered: Does Synchronized method of textWriter do the lock on it (tw)? In case i want to only use Log method from diffrent classes do i need the constructor of this static class and tw variable itself or i can remove it from that class (constructor and tw) and just use Logger.Log() ?

Comment: The Synchronized does make the tw itself thread safe. You can indeed remove the tw member, static constructor and Write method. But then you must always make and pass a TextWriter to the Log method, which might be inconvenient?

Comment: @Mithon still not answer to m y question: Does Synchronized do the lock() on tw? From my logic it does because in same time only one object can access tw because the value is shared accross program (static). If i would use stream reader then i would need to use lock() on it right?

Comment: Like I said, it makes it thread safe. It does not lock it with the _syncObject. It probably does use _a_ lock insternally however. But it could use a semaphore or a mutex or whatever else instead. The docs doesn't say, and I'm not about to look up the source code. :)

Comment: @Mithon please check my second version of class in first post : If i would not use textWriter.Synchronized then if i would use Stream reader for instance then i would need use lock() to achieve same result as textWriter with Synchronized method otherwise threads would access streamreader in same time correct and it could equal to issues. Right?

Comment: last question: If i would add more methods to that class then for each objects which threads would attend to use i need to make lock() right? and _syncObject  will be quiet enough for all of them i dont need to create other variables of lock?

Comment: Yes, you should lock on the same syncObject. Otherwise it won't work. And yes, that's exactly what you will need.

Comment: if i stay Log method only it will be quit enough for me regarding thread safe? thank you very much for explanation !

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `TextWriter` is an abstract class, so the real instance might be any derived class. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.TextWriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on `TextWriter` doesn't guarantee thread-safety of `TextWriter` implementation:

> Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

There is no guarantee that external lock will bring the thread-safety. For example, the implementation may use thread-local storage for its internal data. `TextWriter.Flush` may or may not help, depending on the implementation (but you never know which implementation comes into `Log` method and whether this implementation was e. g. created under the same lock).

This all is about `Log` method.

The usage of `Write`, on the contrary, seems to be good: it uses `TextWriter.Synchronized`, which is thread-safe, according to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter.synchronized%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Creates a thread-safe wrapper around the specified `TextWriter`.

But take into account, that thread-safety of the synchronized text writer may or may not be the thread safety you need: if you are making to consecutive calls to `Log`, the results are not guaranteed to be consecutive in the output file.